# How to put monitors into standby mode during certain hours using Group Policy

Tags: group-policy, scheduled-task

Just a normal Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7/10 office environment with about 35 clients.

I would like to implement a domain-wide power plan for our office computers to put their monitors in standby mode after a certain amount of time, but my boss doesn't like that plan and will only consider implementing a power plan that does that if it can be done during certain hours (that is, during non-work hours). We leave all the computers on overnight and some monitors stay on all night, all the time. Is there a way to implement group policies on a schedule natively in the Group Policy Management Console in Windows Server 2008 R2/2012 R2?

If not, I am open to ideas about how to implement this. One possible plan would be to use GPO to add a scheduled task to each computer which would run a batch file (or change a registry entry/run a script/do something automated) to change the computer's power plan. Then, there would be another scheduled task added to that computer via GPO to turn it back to normal just before working hours start. Any guidance on what's the best plan here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Group Policy Preferences to create a customized power plan and use Item Level Targeting to have the settings applied during your preferred time frame.

Comment: This looks perfect, thanks.